# Django Haystack - Filter by substring of a field using SearchQuerySet ()

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a Django project that uses SOLR for indexing.

I'm trying to do a ***substring search*** using Haystack's **SearchQuerySet** class.

For example, when a user searches for the term ***"ear"***, it should return the entry that has a field with the value: ***"Search"***.
As you can see, ***"ear"*** is a SUBSTRING of ***"Search"***. (obviously :))

In other words, in a perfect Django world I would like something like:

```
SearchQuerySet().all().filter(some_field__contains_substring='ear')
```

In the haystack documentation for **SearchQuerySet** (https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#field-lookups), 
it says that only the following FIELD LOOKUP types are supported:

- contains
- exact
- gt, gte, lt, lte
- in
- startswith
- range

I tried using **__*contains***, but it behaves exactly like **__exact**, which looks up the exact word (the whole word) in a sentence, not a substring of a word.

I am confused, because such a functionality is pretty basic, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or there is another way to approach this problem (using Regex or something?).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That could be done using [EdgeNgramField](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html#subclasses) field:

```
some_field = indexes.EdgeNgramField() # also prepare value for this field or use model_attr
```

Then for partial match:

```
SearchQuerySet().all().filter(some_field='ear')
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is not 100% correct, but it lead me in the right direction. The solution was to use the **NgramField**, not the **EdgeNgramField**, like this: `some_field = indexes.NgramField(model_attr='some_field')`. The **EdgeNgramField** can only do _"starts with"_ and _"ends with"_ type of filtering.

Comment: I wasn't workin with Solr but use **NgramField** worked for me with ElastiSearch.

Comment: EdgeNgram Field is not working like `__contains`, it works by stemming and find other matches based on the stems, hence it'll yield to a much more fuzzy result set than contains.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in haystack.

As you said, `__exact` is implemented exactly like `__contains` and therefore this functionality does not exists out of the box in haystack.

The fix is awaiting merge here: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1041

You can bridge the waiting time for a fixed release like this:

```
from haystack.inputs import BaseInput, Clean


class CustomContain(BaseInput):
    """
    An input type for making wildcard matches.
    """
    input_type_name = 'custom_contain'

    def prepare(self, query_obj):
        query_string = super(CustomContain, self).prepare(query_obj)
        query_string = query_obj.clean(query_string)

        exact_bits = [Clean(bit).prepare(query_obj) for bit in query_string.split(' ') if bit]
        query_string = u' '.join(exact_bits)

        return u'*{}*'.format(query_string)

# Usage:
SearchQuerySet().filter(content=CustomContain('searchcontentgoeshere'))
```