# How to make Django Haystack return Similar Results?

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm using Haystack 2.4.0 and elasticsearch 2.0.0.

I want my search function to be able to return values that are similar to the query. However, following the [Getting Started tutorial of Haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/toc.html), my search queries can only return exact results. For example if I have "football" in my model instance, submitting "football" will in fact return that model instance. But if I type "footballs" or "footbal", nothing is returned.

I've looked around in SO, particularly the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391631/how-do-i-do-a-partial-field-match-using-haystack?lq=1) and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659126/django-haystack-filter-by-substring-of-a-field-using-searchqueryset/33260538#33260538). The `EdgeNgramField` and `NgramField` solutions don't seem to be working for me. I have yet to try the CustomContains bug fix.

Even then, this might solve the problem for typing "footbal", but what about "footballs"?

I'm a beginner in Django, and web development in general actually, so maybe I'm getting it all wrong. How do I make Haystack return similar results as well?

Thanks a ton. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so basically when I got elasticsearch 1.7.4 up and runnung (via brew install elasticsearch) that got it to work. Previously, I was using elasticsearch-2.0.0-rc1 via zip from the elasticsearch downloads page. Not sure if there's a bug there or something.